# Data retrieval to dropdown based on other dropdown trigger?

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a google sheet with a worksheet called "Statuses". I also have a web form in apps script. I want a user to be able to select the parcel drop down and then have this retrieve the MAX value in google sheet associated to that dropdown value:

I select my parcel dropdown, which exists in the worksheet:

[image]

but the status dropdown does not populate with [Negotiating], which is the max status value in this google worksheet:

[image]

here is the code I tried:

```
    function getMaxStatusForParcel(parcel) {
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets...';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
      var statusSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Statuses");
  var lastRow = statusSheet.getLastRow();
  var parcelValues = statusSheet.getRange('A4:A' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var statusValues = statusSheet.getRange('B4:B' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
      
  for (var i = 0; i < parcelValues.length; i++) {
    if (parcelValues[i] === parcel) {
      return statusValues[i];
    }
  }
      
  return ""; // Return empty string if no matching parcel found
}
```

and the onchange event trigger in html:

```
      <label>Parcel</label><br>
      <select name="parcel" id="parcel" onchange="getMaxStatusForParcel(this.value)"></select><br><br>
```

rest of code:

```
    function doGet(e) {
      var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DependentSelect');
      var subs = getDistinctSubstations();
      htmlOutput.message = '';
      htmlOutput.subs = subs;
      return htmlOutput.evaluate();
    }

    function doPost(e) {
      var parcel = e.parameter.parcel.toString();
      var substation = e.parameter.substation.toString();
      var comment = e.parameter.comment.toString();
      var status = e.parameter.status.toString();
      var date = new Date();
      
      addRecord(comment, parcel, date);
      addToStatuses(parcel, status, date);
      
      var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DependentSelect');
      var subs = getDistinctSubstations();
      htmlOutput.message = 'Record Added';
      htmlOutput.subs = subs;
      return htmlOutput.evaluate(); 
    }

    function getStatusOptions(parcel) {
      var maxStatus = getMaxStatusForParcel(parcel);
      var options = ["", "Outreach", "Negotiating", "Signed"];
      var dropdownHTML = options.map(option => {
        if (option === maxStatus) {
          return `<option value="${option}" selected>${option}</option>`;
        } else {
          return `<option value="${option}">${option}</option>`;
        }
      }).join("");
      
      return dropdownHTML;
    }

    function getDistinctSubstations() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var rdSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Raw Data"); 
      var subs = rdSheet.getRange('O4:O' + rdSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().filter((sub, index, self) => self.indexOf(sub) === index && sub !== "");
      return subs;
    }

    function getParcels(substation) {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var rdSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Raw Data"); 
      var lastRow = rdSheet.getLastRow();
      var substationValues = rdSheet.getRange('O4:O' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
      var parcelValues = rdSheet.getRange('A4:A' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
      var filteredParcels = [];
      
      for (var i = 0; i < substationValues.length; i++) {
        if (substationValues[i] === substation && parcelValues[i]) {
          filteredParcels.push(parcelValues[i]);
        }
      }
      
      return filteredParcels.filter(parcel => parcel !== "");
    }

    function getMaxStatusForParcel(parcel) {
      var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets...';
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
      var statusSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Statuses");
      var lastRow = statusSheet.getLastRow();
      var parcelValues = statusSheet.getRange('A4:A' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
      var statusValues = statusSheet.getRange('B4:B' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
      
      for (var i = 0; i < parcelValues.length; i++) {
        if (parcelValues[i] === parcel) {
          return statusValues[i];
        }
      }
      
      return ""; // Return empty string if no matching parcel found
    }

    function addRecord(comment, parcel, date) {
      var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets....';
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
      var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Comments");
      var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yy");
      dataSheet.appendRow([parcel, comment, formattedDate]);
    }

    function addToStatuses(parcel, status, date) {
      var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets....';
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
      var statusSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Statuses");
      var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yy");
      statusSheet.appendRow([parcel, status, formattedDate]);
    }

    function getUrl() {
      var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
      return url;
    }
```

and then html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <base target="_top">
      <style>
        body {
          font-size: 15px;
          background-color: #f0f8ff; /* Light blue background color */
        }
        .container {
          width: 50%;
          margin: 0 auto; /* Center the container horizontally */
          text-align: center; /* Center the content inside the container */
          padding-top: 20px; /* Add space at the top */
        }
        h1 {
          margin-top: 20px; /* Add space between header image and header text */
          font-size: 20px;
        }
        select {
          width: 100%; /* Set the width of dropdown menus to fill the container */
          font-size: 15px; /* Set font size for dropdown values */
        }
        textarea {
          height: 80px;
          font-size: 15px; /* Set font size for textarea */
        }
        input[type="submit"] {
          font-size: 15px; /* Set font size for submit button */
        }
        .submit-message {
          color: red;
          font-size: 15px;
        }
      </style>
      <script>
        function getParcels(substation) {
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(parcels) {
            var parcelDropdown = document.getElementById("parcel");
            parcelDropdown.innerHTML = "";
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = "";
            option.text = "";
            parcelDropdown.appendChild(option);
            parcels.forEach(function(parcel) {
              var option = document.createElement("option");
              option.value = parcel;
              option.text = parcel;
              parcelDropdown.appendChild(option);
            });
          }).getParcels(substation);
        };
        
        function getMaxStatusForParcel(parcel) {
          var statusDropdown = document.getElementById("status");
          if (!parcel) {
            statusDropdown.innerHTML = '<option value=""></option>';
            return;
          }

          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(maxStatus) {
            var options = ["", "Outreach", "Negotiating", "Signed"];
            var dropdownHTML = options.map(option => {
              if (option === maxStatus) {
                return `<option value="${option}" selected>${option}</option>`;
              } else {
                return `<option value="${option}">${option}</option>`;
              }
            }).join("");
            
            statusDropdown.innerHTML = dropdownHTML;
          }).getStatusOptions(parcel);
        }
        
        function validateForm() {
          var parcel = document.getElementById("parcel").value;
          var substation = document.getElementById("substation").value;
          var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;
          var status = document.getElementById("status").value; // Get status value
          
          if (!parcel || !substation || !comment || !status) {
            document.getElementById("submit-message").innerText = "All fields are required.";
            return false; // Prevent form submission
          }
          
          return true; // Allow form submission
        }
      </script>  
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/16QsZja.png" alt="Header Image" style="width: 100%; max-width: 200px;">
        
        <h1>Comment Submission Form</h1>
        
        <? var url = getUrl(); ?>
        <form method="post" action="<?= url ?>" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
          <label>Substation</label><br>
          <select name="substation" id="substation" onchange="getParcels(this.value)">
            <option value=""></option>
            <? for (var i = 0; i < subs.length; i++) { ?>
              <option value="<?= subs[i] ?>"><?= subs[i] ?></option>
            <? } ?>
          </select><br><br>
          
          <label>Parcel</label><br>
          <select name="parcel" id="parcel" onchange="getMaxStatusForParcel(this.value)"></select><br><br>
          
          <label>Status</label><br>
          <select name="status" id="status"></select><br><br>
          
          <label>Comment</label><br>
          <textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea><br><br>
          
          <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit" /> 
          <span id="submit-message" class="submit-message"></span>      
        </form>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with:

```
  function getMaxStatusForParcel(parcel) {
    var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/...';
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var statusSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Statuses");
    var lastRow = statusSheet.getLastRow();
    var parcelValues = statusSheet.getRange('A4:A' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
    var statusValues = statusSheet.getRange('B4:B' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
    var maxStatus = ""; // Initialize maxStatus variable

    // Iterate through rows in reverse order to find the last match
    for (var i = parcelValues.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (parcelValues[i] == parcel && statusValues[i]) { // Ensure correct comparison
        maxStatus = statusValues[i];
        break; // Stop iteration after finding the first match
      }
    }

    return maxStatus; // Return maximum status value
  }
```

and

```
function updateMaxStatusForParcel() {
  var parcel = document.getElementById("parcel").value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(maxStatus) {
    var statusDropdown = document.getElementById("status");
    statusDropdown.innerHTML = ""; // Clear previous options
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = ""; // Set value to empty string
    option.text = ""; // Set text to empty string
    statusDropdown.appendChild(option);
    ["Outreach", "Negotiating", "Signed"].forEach(function(status) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = status;
      option.text = status;
      if (status === maxStatus) {
        option.selected = true; // Select the option if it matches the max status
      }
      statusDropdown.appendChild(option);
    });
  }).getMaxStatusForParcel(parcel);
}
```